# GLX/X11 Changing the rendering resolution

Tags: c++, c, xlib, glx, xrandr

I have made a simple application that creates a window with an OpenGL 4.2 context and takes user input.

I have implemented making the window go fullscreen with XRandR and can change the display resolution.

I would like to change this so that I don't have to set the displays resolution and only the window/contexts so that it renders at a lower resolution but the display stays at its default.

How could I implement this? Which extensions provide this or can I do this with XRandR and just manipulating the window rather than the root window(dektop)?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you understand that screen resolution is how monitor renders VGA/DVI/etc. output and it can't be set per-window?

Comment: I don't want to set the monitor resolution and I wouldn't be asking this question if I didn't have the knowledge to understand the answer.

I settled for setting a framebuffer at a lower resolution to render to then displaying that framebuffer on the window.